# Ubuntu gives "cannot execute binary file" error when I execute C++ program

Tags: c++, bash, visual-studio-2012, g++, executable

I just wrote some code in Visual Studio and am trying the run it on my school's Linux server through shell.  The code runs fine in Visual Studio and complies with `g++` in Linux but won't run with `bash *./a.out*` or `bash *file_name*`.  I imagine there's some syntax I'm using that's acceptable in VS 2012 but doesn't translate into running on the server.

The program is meant to establish if there is union or intersection between the two user entered sets.

Could someone look at my code to tell me what I'm missing?  Thus far I've had to `#include <cstring>` to make it compile but there wasn't anything else besides that.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string set1, set2;
    string extra1[100], extra2[100];
    cout<<"Enter your first set."<<'\n';
    getline(cin,set1);
    char *ch1 = new char[100];
    strcpy(ch1, set1.c_str());
    cout<<"Enter you second set."<<'\n';
    getline(cin,set2);
    char *ch2 = new char[100];
    strcpy(ch2, set2.c_str());
    int z = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < set1.size(); ++i)
    {
        const char c = ch1[i];
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            ++z;
            continue;
        }
        else if (c == ',')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            extra1[z] += ch1[i];    

        }
        else
            continue;
    }   

    int capture = z + 1;
    int r = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < set2.size(); ++i)
    {
        const char c = ch2[i];
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            ++r;
            continue;
        }
        else if (c == ',')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            extra2[r] += ch2[i];    

        }
        else
            continue;
    }   

    int capture2 = r + 1;

    int g = 0;

    string last[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < capture; ++i)
    {
        for(int h = 0; h < capture2; ++h)
        {
            if(extra1[i] == extra2[h])
            {
                last[g] = extra1[i];
                ++g;
            }
        }

    }
    set<string> newset1(last, last+100);
    set<string>::iterator it;
    cout<<"The numbers constitute the intersection between the sets.\n";
    for(it=newset1.begin(); it!=newset1.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it<<' ';

    }   
    cout<<'\n';

    int w = 0;
    string last1[100];

    set<string> newset2(extra1, extra1+100);
    set<string> newset3(extra2, extra2+100);
    newset2.insert(newset3.begin(), newset3.end());
    set<string>::iterator it1;
    cout<<"This set constitutes a union between the two sets."<<'\n';
    for(it1=newset2.begin(); it1!=newset2.end(); ++it1)
    {
        cout << *it1<<' ';
    }   
    cout<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Don't type `bash ./a.out` - with that bash is looking for a text/script file to parse and execute - you are giving it a compiled executable. Just execute the program directly from the command line in Linux. ie type `./a.out`

Comment: @Ozraptor: Expand that a bit, and post it as an answer.

Comment: @user3319779: Welcome to SO! I've tried to improve the formatting around the code in your post; feel free to touch it up further. You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (or a Markdown tutorial) for help on the editor's syntax for questions & answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thanatos.  I was having trouble with that, I'm sure I'll get the hang of it soon.